# Backward motions in Operator-pending mode move cursor

Tags: cursor-movement

If i type, for example, `y/foo<CR>` in Normal mode, i "yank" all the text until the next occurrence of "foo" without side effects.  However, if i type `y?foo<CR>` in Normal mode, i "yank" the text alright, but unfortunately the cursor jumps to the occurrence of "foo".

Is this the expected behavior?  Is there an easy workaround?

Comment: I overlooked the fact that all backward motions move cursor when used in Operator-pending mode.  Thus the initial title of the question ("Using “search backwards” (`?`) in Operator-pending mode") is not particularly appropriate.  I hesitate to remove the question, but i will change the title.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The yank command always places the cursor at the *start* of the yanked text. If you use operator-pending backwards search, you basically have a reverse selection, with the jump target *before* the start.

As the `']` mark has the end of the executed yank, you can return to that original cursor position via `` g`] ``.

Comment: I keep learning how counter-intuitive Vim is!  I didn't notice that `yb` also moves cursor.